# converting embedded unicode characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, unicode

So I've got some data I'm pulling from an API and when I pull it down into my description string it ends up embedded with &nbsp, &mdash, &#10, and other various unicode characters. When I push it to my html page it ends up getting displayed on the view. What can I do to convert this to a readable string?

Is this something I need to parse in my view or in my string on my Controller?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  Are the characters part of your data or do they appear afterwords during view rendering.

Comment: What do you mean displayed on the view  `&nbsp, &mdash, &#10`? Display on a page or in a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the HtmlDecode method from System.Web.HttpUtility class

```
    string yourEncodedString = "&nbsp;&mdash; &#10;";
    Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(yourEncodedString));
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Those particular characters aren't encoded by HtmlEncode, but it's possible the API is encoding them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Html.Raw(yourString)` in your view to display the string as HTML if are sure that it is a valid HTML and **if trust the source and you are sure the the string is not going to be used for [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attack.**

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the answer I ended up going with since I'm just using it for a personal project with non sensitive data but otherwise I think the general answer for me would've been the accepted one above.

Answer (score -3):

you can remove those `character` from the `html string` using this code

```
 str = "1 $nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2 &nbsp; &nbsp; 3 &nbsp; 4"                                
 var new_str = str_replace("&nbsp;", '', $str);
```

Comment: `str_replace`? question is tagged `c#`